# How can I create a pop up like the one Google Calendar uses ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup, twitter-bootstrap

when you click on an empty space in Google Calender in order to add an event or when you click  in an already placed event you will get a very nice popup having info about the event (please see attached image).

How can I create a similar pop up windows using CSS and Javascript (I prefer jQuery). I am also using Bootstrap if that helps.

Please notice that the popup position depends on where I will click so let's say that I have an html table and depending on which  I will click the popup will be generated near to this position and will point to that specific .

Also notice the close behaviour (close button and if I click out of the popup it will close).

If there are more than one good answers I will accept the simplest one that works with jQuery (and jQuery UI) and Bootstrap - I'd grateful if not other frameworks were used.

Thanks !

[image: Google calendar popup]

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow isn't here to do your work for you, we can help you if you're stuck with something specific.

Comment: I believe that my question is specific enough ! I want to create popups ? How can I do it like google ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers contained links about tooltips. However, I believe that a dialog component like the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) would match your requirements better.

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin called jquery tip-tip which might do what you are after. You essentially want to display some HTML above the area you have clicked. Tip-tip can display html as a 'bubble' above the point you have clicked. It's also easy to style. It is mainly used for tooltips but I see no reason why it can't be adapted to do this.

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

(p.s. you would need to use the 'content' property to set the content)

```
"content: string (false by default) - HTML or String to use as the content for TipTip. 
Will overwrite content from any HTML attribute."
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are talking regarding the `tooltips` here is link which will help you

**http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html**

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/06/12/tooltips-scripts-ajax-javascript-css-dhtml/

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this did not exist back in March when this question was asked, but current version of Bootstrap has popovers like the one in the question.  See:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers

Comment: Bootstrap rulz ! I like the new features :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FireBug to analyse the page and check the actual values for CSS properties (ie. what colour is the border, or how much padding is there).